# Getting exception, "The specified content type is invalid", when sending 2 inline images via Mail?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, smtp, html-email

I am trying to add 2 images in my mail that I am sending, but currently
I am getting

> exception The specified content type is invalid.

```
dynamic htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(_Body.ToString(), null, "text/html");
LinkedResource logo = new LinkedResource(_EmailLogo, _EmailLogo1);
logo.ContentId = "Dexuslogo1";
logo.ContentId = "Dexuslogo2";
htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(logo);
aMessage.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);
```

pls help me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: **logo** is a single linked resource; not a collection. You would need to add a second liked resource for the second image

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the `_EmailLogo` and `_EmailLogo1` variables are strings containing the filename of two images.

Have a look at the documentation for the [LinkedResource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144663(v=vs.110).aspx) class, two strings as parameters in the constructor, the second string is the content type. A filename is not a content type.

To add two images, you would simply repeat the process for adding a single image.

```
dynamic htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(_Body.ToString(), null, "text/html");

LinkedResource logo1 = new LinkedResource(_EmailLogo);
logo1.ContentId = "Dexuslogo1";
htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(logo1);

LinkedResource logo2 = new LinkedResource(_EmailLogo1);
logo2.ContentId = "Dexuslogo2";
htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(logo2);

aMessage.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);
```